# How to find XPath of select file button?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to click on Select file button. Have tried by using following XPath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-modal-body']//button[contains(@class,'ant-btn-ghost')]/i")).click();
```

But the above code didn't work for me.

Following is the code which I get after pressing F12:

```
<button class="ant-btn ant-btn-ghost" type="button">
<i class="anticon anticon-upload"/>
<span> Select File </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Try. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Select File']")).click();`. If it doesn't work, check whether button located inside an `iframe` or apply Explicit/Implicit wait

Comment: @Andersson thanks a lot man it worked for me after adding above code and Thread.sleep(2000);

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comments that you solved your issue through `Thread.sleep(2000)` that would be against all the *Best Practices*. To to click on the button with text as **Select file** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following line of code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='ant-modal-body']//button[@class='ant-btn ant-btn-ghost']//span[contains(.,'Select File')]"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

First try with :

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'SelectFile')]")).click();
```

If it doesn't work try :

```
    WebElement composeBtn = driver.findElement(By.className("ant-btn ant-btn-ghost"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", composeBtn);
```